# Is it possible to pass through Creative Sound Blaster AE-9 to a Windows VM while working in Linux

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, audio, drivers

Considering to switch to Linux as primary OS. Which distro is not important (I guess). The only thing stopping me from switching OS is a driver for Creative Sound Blaster AE-9 sound card. It is not available under Linux. To resolve the driver issue I can run Windows in VM, so the card will have a proper driver.

My question is - is it possible? Does anyone have experience with this kind of setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *possible* with qemu/kvm, since it supports PCI(e) passthrough, given your hardware (CPU+motherboard) supports IOMMU virtualization (conned "VT-d" and "AMD-Vi" by Intel and AMD respectively).

To have it done, you literally have to unbind the PCI(e) device from its original/"specific" driver on the host/hypervisor and bind it to the `vfio-pci` driver (which is essentially a "generic" one) that is for the passing-through.

It is *not guaranteed* to work or work very well on every hardware platform for every device though, especially if you are after an "audiophile experience". It is relatively likely for you to experience audio jumps. It might requires you to "tune" a bunch of qemu flags (specific to virtualizing Windows or related to "clock", whatever that could be referring to) before you can get an acceptable "performance".

Also with "stable" distro that likes to stick with "ancient" version of kernel, it might perform worse as well because it lacks the newer optimizations in vfio-pci.

Finally, in case you are confused, having a VM that supports the hardware running doesn't automagically make the hardware "available" on the host. Often you can at best make it "happen" by using e.g. virtual network. In this case it could be something like setting up a PulseAudio server (which is pretty much unmaintained / unsupported in Windows) in the guest and play sound over the network from the host.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough answer.
I think I understand what you mean by audio jumps. This type of stuff comes up with a sound from guest VM(s).
Would there be a way to assign 1-2 cores directly to particular VM (Windows) in qemu/kvm? With a hope this would resolve the issue.

Comment: You can set the number of cores/threads to emulate, which AFAIK would determine how many threads qemu has, but there are more complications behind the scene regarding that I think, and I don't know it very well. Either way, AFAIK the cause is often not about processing power, but rather precision of "clock(s)" and whether vfio-pci would hiccup under circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Generally no.

Virtual Box (which you are using) and VMware do not pass through all Video / Sound hardware for independent install in the Guest machine.

I think you may find that, since not (likely) installed in the Linux host, that pass through will not work.

Also there is a bit of a difference between (1) just connecting host hardware and (2) making (say) the host USB available for use in the VM to install a USB device.

Whatever hardware a Guest might use must be installed in the Host:  Video, Audio, Network, Main Drive, CD, Printer, Mouse and so on.

You can try a trial version of VMware to see if the existing connections provided will help you with the Creative Blaster card.  My own VMware only allows connection of host hardware, including USB which I can use in the Guest machine.

Comment: Some time ago I heard "finally Nvidia fixed it" which was related to a pass through issue with video card. Was it a fix on a host side of the driver?

Comment: Likely yes, Host Windows SIde.

Comment: Nvidia had broken it on purpose IIRC, and folks found out how to work around it first.

Comment: That was also a while back.  Today the general outline I have posted is how VMs work now.